# How can i fix this error?? TypeError: 'list' object is not callable on line 17

Tags: python-3.x

```
def last_four(x):
    return x[-4:]
        

ids = [17573005, 17572342, 17579000, 17570002, 17572345, 17579329]
ids2=[]
for i in ids:
    ids2.append(str(i))
sorted_ids=sorted(ids2,key=last_four(ids2))
print(sorted_ids)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass the list to the `key` parameter of the `sorted` function. Internally python takes care of it

```
In [48]: def last_four(x):
    ...:     return x[-4:]
    ...:
    ...:
    ...: ids = [17573005, 17572342, 17579000, 17570002, 17572345, 17579329]
    ...: ids2=[]
    ...: for i in ids:
    ...:     ids2.append(str(i))
    ...: sorted_ids=sorted(ids2,key=last_four)
    ...: print(sorted_ids)
['17570002', '17572342', '17572345', '17573005', '17579000', '17579329']
```